# how can I see which ejabberd messages are, and are not, delivered?

Tags: ejabberd

I need to write a server-side app which is able to see which messages have been delivered and which have not.

Messages are sent with a XEP-0184 delivery request element, and the recipients are correctly sending XEP-0184 delivery reponses.

Ideally I'd like to be able to derive this from the Postgresql database, but I can't see anywhere the DR response is recorded.

If the only way I can achieve this is with a custom-module, then any hints about what to hook would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to implement in the server for XEP-0184, in particular, storing or keeping track of those stanzas.

Maybe XEP-0313 MAM could help here?

For your own module that would implement this, I guess you can look at modules that handle/log/sniff/filter stanzas, like mod_message_log, mod_filter, mod_spam:filter, mod_log_chat, mod_pottymouth, and later look at modules that use the ETS or Mnesia storages.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. You'r right I was slightly barking up the wrong tree. However I still can't figure something out. If A sends a message to B (offline), I can see the message in the archive table, but I can't see any indication that it is yet to be delivered. When B comes online, he receives the message embedded in a mam stanza. What I can't figure out is where in the database is it recorded that B hadn't yet received that message, ie. that it was undelivered (albeit not in the xep-0184 sense).